# Using data variables for data links in grafana

Tags: grafana

I have a panel using mysql as data source. I selected 5 fields, one of them is time. So the panel looks fine. I want to use data links to redirect to another dashboard/panel. The other panel takes a variable, and it will display the contents based on the variable's value. I want to pass the value of a specific metric at the place where the cursor is, in this case, `run_id`.

I've been trying to do the data links as

```
http://localhost:8080/d/_B2a2xXZk/target?orgId=1&fullscreen&var-run_id=${__data.fields[run_id].numeric}
```

, this doesn't seem to work. When it opens the other dashboard, the value is not injected. I also tried to use `${__data.fields[run_id]}`, that doesn't seem to work either.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide your query ?

Comment: The source is using the query of `select metric_a, run_id, time from table1` to produce the dashboard, and the target dashboard is using `select metric_b from table2 where run_id = $run_id`. So I want to use the `run_id` value at a given time from source, to change target dashboard.

Comment: Try aliasing run_id to a field name without special character (i.e runid) . , ive had some problems with field names in data links in the past

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that doesn't seem like the problem for me on this one. It's still not interpreting the value.

Comment: your syntax is correct, id suggest raising a bug on github :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ${__all_variables} variable at the end of link where you want to redirect. And put the $run_id in the next panel. SO it will take the run_id variable value of previous panel.